# How many presenters do I need in the MVP pattern

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I'm trying to understand MVP pattern in c# winforms.
My question is do I have to create presenter class for each entity? For, example: In my Application I have:

- **Form1**, in that form `Students` will list on a Listbox
- **Form2**, in that form `Orders` will list on a Listbox
- **Form3**, in that form `Details` will list on a Listbox

So in my Presenter application do I have to create?:

**StudentPresenter.cs**
**OrderPresenter.cs**
**DetailsPresenter.cs**

If yes, suppose I have a button in my `Form1`, when I click that button I want to show `Form2`. Is my code below true?

```
    private void showForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var orderForm= new Form2();
        var orderRepo= new OrderRepository();
        var orderPresenter = new OrderPresenter(orderForm, orderRepo);
        //How I show Form2 ?
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, what I have seen so far using the MVP-Pattern was to use One Presenter per View, in other words, it doesn't matter how many Models you have, the amount is decoupled from the amount of presenters. Also, in the project I worked previously, before switching to MVVM, the One-Presenter-Per-View was adhered to rigorously.

This question has been asked several times here, in one form or another.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856150/mvp-pattern-how-many-views-to-a-presenter) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700592/how-many-presenters-should-be-used-in-model-view-presenter-with-winforms-with-ta).